# JOLT Transform to Concatenate 2 Rows, with No Array

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I'm trying to transform the 2 rows of a JSON file into a single value.

Source is:

```json
[
  {
    "DETAIL": "<html><head><style>table {border-collapse: collapse;  width: 60%; table-layout: fixed;} html,body,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5 </style></head><body>"
  },
  {
    "DETAIL": "<body><br><br><h2>CRUDs</h2><table> <tr><th style=\"width:40%\">TABLE_NAME</th><th style=\"width:30%\">INSERTS</th><th style=\"width:30%\">UPDATES</th><tr><td>CONTACT</td></body></html>"
  }
]
```

The desired output is:

```json
{
  "DETAIL" : "<html><head><style>table {border-collapse: collapse;  width: 60%; table-layout: fixed;} html,body,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5 </style></head><body><body><br><br><h2>CRUDs</h2><table> <tr><th style=\"width:40%\">TABLE_NAME</th><th style=\"width:30%\">INSERTS</th><th style=\"width:30%\">UPDATES</th><tr><td>CONTACT</td></body></html>"
}
```

My current spec is:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "DETAIL": "DETAIL"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

This kind of works but returns the value as an array, like this

```json
{
  "DETAIL" : ["<html><head><style>table {border-collapse: collapse;  width: 60%; table-layout: fixed;} html,body,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5 </style></head><body><body><br><br><h2>CRUDs</h2><table> <tr><th style=\"width:40%\">TABLE_NAME</th><th style=\"width:30%\">INSERTS</th><th style=\"width:30%\">UPDATES</th><tr><td>CONTACT</td></body></html>"]
}
```

I'd appreciate some help in getting this sorted, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Symbolically your first spec is this

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

convert it to the following one by adding a **modify** transformation spec which ***join***s those components of the array :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=join('',@(1,&))"
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Comment: It's true and the only best answer to this question. Great.